# fvm keep requesting change flutter path

Tags: flutter, dart, fvm

I am trying to use fvm on Windows.
Because my projects use mixed of languages, I need to change the version globally.
The problem is that it keeps asking me to change the flutter path.
At first,

[image: fvm]

So, I moved flutter path down to the bottom of fvm\default\bin.
Here is how I setup the path.

[image: fvm2]

Now, if I change global flutter version again, the path is changed as the version of fvm, not the default... which is not in the path at all.

[image: fvm3]

If it is just the message, I can ignore, but when I try to open up my project and try `flutter --version` the global version is not changed.

Can anybody guess what is the problem?

I did install with `flutter pub global activate fvm`.
I tried deactivate and activate again, removed reset the path in various ways, but keep getting same issue.

Another thing is I am keep getting `Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid SDK hash` message. I just assume this is kind of related to the first issue, but not of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved this issue.

First of all, I had flutter installed version 1.22.6 at the beginning. and installed fvm with `flutter pub global activate fvm`. Then, the fvm version 1.3.7 installed. If I try to install flutter version 3.x.x, it fails with message like `Internal Error: Could not infer Flutter Version 3.x.x` or `fvm version 1.3.7 doesn't support ~~~` something like that. So, I upgraded the actual flutter installed to the latest version, and also upgraded fvm to the latest version. Then, it never go back to 1.22.6 globally with the fvm.

So, I reinstalled the flutter version 1.22.6, complete uninstall fvm by `flutter pub global deactivate fvm` and also deleting fvm folder.(if you don't delete the folder and reinstall, it will install the same version of fvm you previously installed) And reinstall with `flutter pub global activate fvm`. Then, it will then install fvm 1.3.7 version. With this version of fvm, I couldn't install 3.0.2, but could install `stable`
but using different commands for this fvm 1.3.7 version.... like `fvm use stable --global`... you can find some commands [here](https://pub.dev/packages/fvm/versions/1.3.7)
it was because of the actual flutter version installed and fvm version I guess.... Please comment below if I was wrong.